# Cannot open file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, thonny

I am trying to execute a python file from my python code that I am using.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *


def send():
    exec(open('usersend.py').read())



with open("User_Data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read() ##Assume the sample file has 3 lines
    second = lines.split()[2]


root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='Welcome, ' + second + ' to Jammer!')
label.config(font=('Courier', 44))
label.pack()

button = Button(root, text='Send a game', command = send)
button.config(font=('Courier', 10))
button.pack(side = 'bottom', expand = False, padx = 4, pady = 4)
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/saish/programs/User2.py", line 5, in send
    exec(open('usersend.py').read())
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/plugins/cpython/cpython_backend.py", line 1205, in readline
    return self._generic_read("readline", limit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/plugins/cpython/cpython_backend.py", line 1193, in _generic_read
    "Wrong type of command (%r) when waiting for input" % (msg,)
RuntimeError: Wrong type of command (ToplevelCommand(source='dfgdfg\n', tty_mode=True, id='cmd_13', local_cwd='/home/pi/saish/programs', expected_cwd='/home/pi/saish/programs', name='execute_source', argv=[])) when waiting for input
```

I want to be able to run this code succesfully.

Comment: This is a Thonny issue. See https://github.com/thonny/thonny/issues/1207

Comment: @Barmar How do I ctrl + D in python IDE? (I want to stop writing the multiple line thing)

Comment: Most people do it by having the user enter a special value to indicate that it's the last input, rather than using EOF.